# Conan.io use on embeddeds Software development

Tags: embedded, conan, automotive

Please allow me two questions to the use in `Conan.io` in our environment:

We are developing automotive embedded software. Usually, this includes integration of COTS libraries, most of all for communication and OS like AUTOSAR. These are provided in source code. Typical uC are Renesas RH850, RL78, or similar devices from `NXP`, `Cypress`, `Infinion`, and so on. We use `gnumake` (MinGW), Jenkins for CI, and have our own EclipseCDT distribution as standardized IDE.

**My first question:**

Those 3rd party components are usually full of conditional compilation to do a proper compile-time configuration. With this approach, the code and so the resulting binaries are optimized, both in size and in run-time behavior.

Besides those components, we of course have internal reusable components for different purposes. The Compile-time configuration here is not as heavy as in the above example, but still present.

In one sentence: we have a lot of compile-time configuration - what could be a good approach to set up a JFrog / Conan based environment? Stay with the sources in every project?

**XRef with Conan:**

Is there a way to maintain cross-reference information coming from Conan? I am looking for something like "Project xxx is using Library lll Version vvv". In that way, we would be able to automatically identify other "users" of a library in case a problem is detected.

Thanks a lot,
Stefan

Comment: Hi @Stefan, I have responded to the first question, but the second one is not fully clear. Projects or packages declare which version they are using, explicitly, like ``requires = "pkg/version"``. Please clarify what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Conan recipes are based on python and thus are very flexible, being able to implement any conditional logic that you might need.

As an example, the `libxslt` [recipe in ConanCenter](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/a79d9f7f0c2b61c3e137720a917313c717761720/recipes/libxslt/all/conanfile.py#L53) contains something like:

```
def build(self):
    self._patch_sources()
    if self._is_msvc:
        self._build_windows()
    else:
        self._build_with_configure()
```

And following this example, the autotools build contains code like:

```
def _build_with_configure(self):
        env_build = AutoToolsBuildEnvironment(self, win_bash=tools.os_info.is_windows)
        full_install_subfolder = tools.unix_path(self.package_folder)
        # fix rpath
        if self.settings.os == "Macos":
            tools.replace_in_file(os.path.join(self._full_source_subfolder, "configure"), r"-install_name \$rpath/", "-install_name ")
        configure_args = ['--with-python=no', '--prefix=%s' % full_install_subfolder]
        if self.options.shared:
            configure_args.extend(['--enable-shared', '--disable-static'])
        else:
            configure_args.extend(['--enable-static', '--disable-shared'])
```

So Conan is able to implement any compile time configuration. That doesn't mean that you need to build always from sources. The parametrization of the build is basically:

- Settings: for "project wide" configuration, like the OS or the architecture. Settings values typically have the same value for all dependencies
- Options: for package specific configuration, like a library being static or shared. Every package can have its own value, different to other packages.

You can implement the variability model for a package with settings and options, build the most used binaries. When a given variant is requested, Conan will error saying there is not precompiled binary for that configuration. Users can specify `--build=missing` to build those from sources.